# Maximal cycle on n items

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, extremal-graph-theory

Suppose $n$ items are in a circle. What is the maximal cycle length that goes through all of the items. Length between 2 points is measured according to the shorter arc on the circle.
I solved the problem for odd $n$ (it's $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$). For even $n$ I proved lower bound of $\frac{n^2}{2}-n+2$.
 here's an example for $n=12$ (this construction generalized is how I showed the bound):[image]

In other words I ask why I can't build a better example.

Comment: For even $n$, the biggest move you can make is $n/2$, which can be followed by $n/2 -1$; there are no longer moves. The $(n/2)$th jump of $n/2$ will land you at point $n$, so the cycle is completed by a move of 1. That's $(n/2)(n/2) + (n/2-1)(n/2-1) +1$, which is equal to $n^2/2 -n +2$, which is therefore also the upper bound.

Comment: If I understood correctly you showed an example of a cycle of length $n^2/2−n+2$. That shows only lower bound for the problem. For an upper bound we need to show every other cycle must be the same length or shorter.

Comment: It's possible I misunderstood you, and certainly what I've shown was highly informal. What sort of answer are to looking for then? Proof of the upper bound?

Comment: I want the upper bound, yes. I don't care about formality for this question.

Comment: Yeah, your edit is basically the same result I have. I'm uncertain why you're calling it a lower bound, though; clearly the lower bound would just be $n$, right? Sadly I don't see a way to construct an example with a higher value, but I'm not sure I can prove it can't be done.

Comment: For even $n$, there are only $n/2$ moves of length $n/2$ possible; the remaining $n/2$ moves are all of length at most $n/2 - 1$. So, an easy upper bound would be $(n/2)(n/2) + (n/2)(n/2 - 1) = n^2/2 - n/2$. This is already close to but not quite yet the conjectured optimum

Comment: Using dynamic programming I verified for $n \le 26$ that your example is optimal

Comment: @EricSnyder The question asks for the length of the longest cycle so the terms _lower bound_ and _upper bound_ refer to bounds for this _optimal_ value. Your construction shows that the optimum is not smaller than $(n^2/2-n+2)$ (which is thus _lower bound_ for the optimum), while Mike Daas' comment proves that the optimum cannot exceed $(n^2/2-n/2)$ (and thus is the upper bound).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $C$ be a valid cycle. We're going to find an upper bound to $length(C)$.
Cycle $C'$ is formed by visiting every 2nd vertex of $C$.
[image]

Now consider the $\frac{n}{2}$ triangles formed by each edge of $C'$ and the corresponding skipped point.

[image]

The edges of edges of $C$ and $C'$ are exactly covered by the $\frac{n}{2}$ triangles.  So,
$$
length(C) + length(C') = \sum{\text{triangle perimeter}}\tag{1}
$$
A triangle has a maximum perimeter of $n$. So,
$$
\sum{\text{triangle perimeter}}\le\frac{n}{2}\cdot n\tag{2}
$$
$C'$ has $\frac{n}{2}$ vertices, so two of those vertices must be at least
$\frac{n}{2}-1$ apart. So,
$$
length(C')\ge (\frac{n}{2}-1)\cdot 2\tag{3}
$$
Combining these formulas gives
$$
length(C)\le\frac{n^2}{2}-n+2\tag{4}
$$

**My thought process**

I worked with $n=12$, like in the example. I found it easier to grasp the problem by changing edge costs to $\frac{n}{2}-distance$ and then *minimizing* the total cost.

Now, moving to the opposite vertex costs $0$, and we want to prove the total cost will be at least $10$.

[image]

In the example, the path $0$-$6$-$1$-$7$-$2$-$8$...$5$-$11$-$0$ has costs $0$, $1$, $0$, $1$, ..., $0$, $5$. At some point I drew a line from $0$ to $1$ to visualize the $1$ cost of $0$-$6$-$1$. Then a line from $1$ to $2$ to visualize the $1$ cost of $1$-$7$-$2$. I repeated this, and happily the drawing the line from $5$ to $0$ also made sense to show the $5$ cost of $5$-$11$-$0$. So, basically, I stumbled into drawing $C'$ and realized that it neatly ties everything together.

Comment: *$C′$ has $\frac n2$ vertices, so two of those vertices must be at least $\frac n2 - 1$ apart.* It makes sense to prove such statement, it doesn't look obvious. I have an idea that is not graceful, but rigorous. Let's suppose that each pair is at most $\frac n2 - 2$ apart. Each vertex of $C'$ forbids three other vertices to appear in $C'$. On the other hand each vertex is forbidden by at most three other vertices. The number of vertices in the cycle equals to the number of forbidden vertices. That's why each vertex not belonging to the cycles is forbidden by exactly three vertices.

Comment: It means that both neighbors of a vertex of the cycle also belong to the cycle. Such a cycle on $\frac n2$ vertices can't exist and this proves the statement.

Comment: Thanks, though, I'm a bit confused by your logic at the end. Here's a little modification I like:

There are $\frac{n}{2}$ pairs of "opposite" vertices. Exactly 1 of each pair must be selected*. Consider vertex **a** in C'. It forbids three other vertices like you said (the opposite and the opposite's neighbors). This means that the opposites of those three vertices must be in C'. This shows that both neighbors of any vertex in C' must also be in C' -- which forces all $n$ vertices to be selected, a contradiction.

Comment: *(Selecting both vertices violates the max distance, so 1 of each is necessary to reach $\frac{n}{2}$ vertices.)

Comment: I meant that $\frac n2$ vertices of $C'$ forbid $\frac{3n}2$ vertices up to their multiplicity. Since each of $\frac n2$ vertices can be forbidden at most $3$ times, then it is forbidden exactly $3$ times. But your idea about pairs of opposite vertices may be even better

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution, it's really awesome. Actually I asked this question originally because I haven't seen similar problems. Maybe if it's not a great hassle you could explain what caused you to introduce this $C'$ subgraph? Or maybe if you could reference a similar problem that sparked this idea? At any rate, you got your deserved bounty :)

Comment: Thanks! It was a fun problem. Much trickier than I thought it would be! I haven't seen a problem like it. 

I added a section to explain my thoughts.